# hibernate custom DDL creating

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have my custom sql file with DDL queries. I need to init my schemes with this file.
Not by

```
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

How i can do that?

Comment: Are you using Spring or any other framework like that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a special filename called `import.sql` which you can include in the root of your application's classpath which Hibernate will look for after creating the database schema, allowing users to contribute additional SQL commands that Hibernate should execute at bootstrap.

You can influence this special filename by adjusting the following property:

```
// default setting
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files="/import.sql"
```

Should you need to import multiple files, you can specify them using this property setting using a comma-delimited pattern, e.g. `/import1.sql,/import2.sql`.